# swift - cellforrowindexpath "index out of range" error

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am getting "index out of range" error randomly in my tableview which I use for search function.

It crashes at `cell.article = self.searchResults?[indexPath.row]`

99% of the time it works, but sometimes even if I use the same search query it gives this error and crashes.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        self.searchResults?.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        if (!searchController.searchBar.text!.isEmpty){
            let query = ["q" : searchController.searchBar.text]
            let start = 1
            let size = 15
            let index = "articles"
            let parameters : [String : AnyObject] = ["index": index, "query": String(query), "start": start, "size": size]
            let url = "http://api.url"
            Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    guard response.result.error == nil else {
                        print(response.result.error!)
                        debugPrint(response)
                        return
                    }
                    if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
                        let search = JSON(value)
                        if let data = search["articles"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                            self.searchResults = data
                            self.view.hideLoading()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchCell") as! SearchTableViewCell        
            let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SearchTableViewController.longPressCell(_:)))
            gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
            cell.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

            cell.article = self.searchResults?[indexPath.row] ---> "EXC_BREAKPOINT" here. 
            cell.authorButton.tag = indexPath.row

            return cell
        }
```

Comment: can you post your numberOfRowsInSection method as well?

Comment: After an asynchronous request the table view is supposed to be reloaded on the main thread

Comment: I guess the problem is that your `searchResults` array does not contain a row that matches `indexPath.row`. For instance, if `searchResults` only contains 1 element and your `indexPath.row` = 2, then you will see this crash. Perhaps you should try to debug what your `searchResults` contains when it crashes.

Comment: can you post you're other table view delegate methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you are removing all data

```
self.searchResults?.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
```

you are not reloading `tableView`, and until `self.tableView.reloadData()` will be called in Alamofire completion your `tableView` can crash. You can reload `tableView` just after removing elements, or just don't remove them, they will be anyway overriden by new on Alamofire completion

Comment: I think this solves my problem, I need to test more to replikate the issue. Thank you Shadow Of.